# Issue with writing output of ping command to a text file in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, file-io, accessibility, ping

Below is my code that will be called by each thread in order to write the output of ping command to a text file. The file is created properly but there is nothing in it. For now i did not create any threads and just called the function like this from main:

```
customPing("www.google.com", 10, 2, 1);


void customPing(char *url, int test_interval,int samplesPerTest, int testDuration)
{
    printf("-->%s %d(sec) %d %d(hrs)\n", url, test_interval, samplesPerTest, testDuration);

    int durationInProgress = 0,
        durationInSeconds = testDuration * 10,
        n = samplesPerTest;

    char pingCmd[80];
    char filename[10];

    FILE *fptr;

    sprintf(filename, "pingResult%d.txt", fileCounter++);
    fptr = fopen(filename, "a");

    sprintf(pingCmd, "ping -n %d %s >> %s ", n, url,filename);

    printf("ping command: %s\n", pingCmd);

    while (durationInProgress <= durationInSeconds )
    {
        system(pingCmd);

        durationInProgress += test_interval;

        printf("Going to sleep...\n");
        fclose(fptr);
        Sleep(test_interval);
        fptr = fopen(filename, "a");
    }

    printf("***Done***\n");
}
```

---

OUTPUT:

---

```
1. Enter url: www.google.ca

2. Enter Testing-Interval(10 sec, 20 sec, etc): 10

3. Test Samples per test (10, 100 etc): 2

4. Start test (yes/no): yes

4. Test Duration ( 1 hr, 24 hrs, etc) 1
        ***Test Starting***
-->www.google.com 10(sec) 2 1(hrs)
ping command: ping -n 2 www.google.com >> pingResult0.txt
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Going to sleep...
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Going to sleep...
***Done***
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any ideas on what am i doing wrong???
I am using Visual Studio 2008, Win vista.(if that helps)
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of directing ping's output to a file, then reading the file, why not just use `popen` to pipe the result from ping directly back to the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>To write to the file you must use `fprintf`, not `printf` or `sprintf`!</s>

---

Don't use `FILE*` operations in your code. The output is automatically redirected to the correct file, and if you try to use the file from inside the program at the same time, bad things happen.

Just simply `system("cmd >> file")` and the output of "cmd" will end up in the file.

Comment: but i have my command setup like this: ping -n 2 >> filename.txt, and i though >> will take care of writing to a text file. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: sprintf writes to a string, thats how i make up my filename

Comment: yea i looked at the code after a hot coffee and i am like if i am using >> then why FILE *. The other thing was the filename array, its length is 10, i made it 20 and is fine now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

why are you opening the file in this program before running the ping command

I suspect the ping fails to write to the file but you dont see the stderr output.

run the command then open the file in read mode